# Merchants credit card transaction history

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

I am looking for a payment gateway that would allow me to check the history of all credit card transactions and generate a report of that.

Is there any service that would allow me to get this info (amount, date, time, user id) on behalf of the merchant regardless of credit card used?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.Net offers a [transaction details API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/) that allows you to access that data for report generation.